# R function to put a flag

Tags: r

I have written a r function to flag 1 for male and 2 for female.But the code is not running what am i doing wrong here.
my dataframe(name of dataframe=input)
Name  gender
Anu    F
tom    M
john   M
Mary    J
I want to introduce a new column in this having 1 for M and 2 for F.
I have written the below code

```
f1 <- function(gender,category) {
  if(gender == "M") {
    category=1
    category
   } else {
     category=2
     category
  } 

 }
 f1(input$gender,input$category)
```

Comment: your function is not returning anything plus, `if`cannot deal with vector of multiple condition. a simple way to do what you want is `input$category[input$gender=="M"] <- 1` and similar for "F". Or `input$category <- input$gender!="M"+1`

Comment: @CathG intersting approach to use a function but still make it a one-liner

Comment: @Pierre, indeed ;-) `f1 <- function(gender){(gender!="M") + 1} and then category <- f1(gender)` will work better and then `input$category <- f1(input$gender)`

Comment: Why is `category` an argument to the function if you intend to add it as a new column?

Comment: @brittenb thanks, you can add the option in your answer as alternative if you like

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with your function. The first is that you're passing a category variable in your function definition when you shouldn't be. You really just want to pass in the gender and have it return a 1 or a 2 depending on what `input$gender` equals. Second, as stated in the comments, `if` doesn't like a vector of arguments in its condition; it'll only use the first element of `input$gender`. Third, you're not assigning the returned value from your function to your dataset.

To get this to work, you'd want to rewrite the function to take only one element at a time and then return a number. You'd then use this in conjunction with `sapply` or something like that. What would be more appropriate would be to just use the `ifelse` function that R already provides. It would look like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(name = c("Anu", "Tom", "John", "Mary"), gender = c("F", "M", "M", "F"), stringsAsFactors = F)
dat$category <- ifelse(dat$gender == "M", 1, 2)
```

Note that `ifelse` is different from the typical `if/else` combo you see in code. This function is designed to take a vector of elements and loop over them. I'd highly recommend reading the materials in `?ifelse`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot.I made the functionf1 <- function(gender){ifelse(gender=="M",1,2)}
 input$category <- f1(input$gender)

Answer (score -4):

Maybe with `dplyr`:

```
library("dplyr")

input %>%
     mutate(new_sex=ifelse(gender=="M", 1, 2))
```

Comment: really, you think it needs pipes and additional package ?

Comment: But I want to write a function and use it dynamically for any datasets I have

Comment: You don't even need an outside package. You can just use the `ifelse` command from base R.

Comment: `dplyr` is easy and the code is clearer than yours  It is easy to make a function of that. `f1 <- funciton(input) {input %>% mutate(new_sex=ifelse(gender=="M", 1, 2))}`

Comment: Because it's an unnessecary use of dplyr.

Comment: @Marta, you really think your code is easier than just `new_sex=ifelse(gender=="M", 1, 2)` ?

Comment: Yes, because you don't need to do `cbind` later.

Comment: @Marta, I don't `cbind` : `input$category <- ...` will create the column, no need for `cbind`

Comment: By 'column' I understand an old dataset with a new column.

Comment: Original dataset plus new column